# Customize Editview in Custom Safe Manner

Tags: sugarcrm

Is there a way to customize module(Eg:Contacts) in an custom safe manner.
My requirement is too load one javascript in editview of Contacts module.
I have currently called the js in custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php and have created an addon for same.
But when I will upload the addon , if that file custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php already present will be overridden.
Is there an other way to do the same which do not removes customizations?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
<?php
require_once("modules/Contacts/views/view.edit.php");
class CustomContactsViewEdit extends ContactsViewEdit
{
     public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
     }

     public function display(){
        parent::display();
        //Load your javascript file here
     }

}
```

OR You can include your javascript file on the editviewdefs metadata.

```
$viewdefs['Contacts']['EditView]['templateMeta']['includes][] = array(
    'file' => 'custom/modules/Contacts/CustomJs.js',
);
```

Havent checked this code but it will surely work.